# Is it possible to create a table in MySQL using a prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Is it possible to create a table in MySQL with a prepared statement?  I have the following statement, which selects columns from one table using criteria from a second table, and want to create a table containing the results:

```
SET @sql = (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='mpi_install') a
JOIN display_data
ON display_data.display_data_name = a.column_name
WHERE display_data.display_summary = "1"
AND display_data.phase_name="mpi_install"
);

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, 'FROM mpi_install');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The output from this is (with bogus test data):

```
+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| http_username | platform_hardware | test_result | start_timestamp     |
+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| name1         | platform1         | result1     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| name2         | platform2         | result2     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| name3         | platform3         | result3     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| name4         | platform4         | result4     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| name5         | platform5         | result5     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| name6         | platform6         | result6     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| name7         | platform7         | result7     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| name8         | platform8         | result8     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

The original table mpi_install has many more columns, and display_data defines which columns will be displayed from this and other tables.

Comment: Did you try it? What is the result?

Comment: This statement works and returns the desired columns of data, but as currently constructed only prints them to the screen (see edit above for results).  I want to take this data and instead store it as a new table or view, with just these columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `name` AS SELECT ', @sql, 'FROM mpi_install');
```

Comment: Thank you!  I must have messed up quotes or something, because that was not working an hour ago.